# sum two dates in node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js

i'm trying to sum two dates.

date1 and date2 are Date() objects.

i read oher questions and googled it.. i tryed this way but it return a negative number

```
var sum_millis = date1.getTime()+date2.getTime();

var sum=new Date(sum_millis);

console.log(sum.toString());
```

date1:  1901-02-01T00:10:00.000Z

date2:  1901-01-31T23:07:23.000Z

result:  -4349551357000

what i'm doing wrong?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/x2yore52/ works for me.. what do you expect. Give us an example

Comment: What do you mean by _it doesn't work_? Could you maybe explain a little bit more what you're trying to archive? Do you want to sum the complete timestamps or only e.g. day or minute ranges?

Comment: If the Date object is constructed with invalid parameters then its `.getTime` method will return `NaN`. `NaN` is viral: any mathematical operation performed using `NaN` yields `NaN`. One or both of your Date objects is likely malformed. Call `.toString()` on your dates, if they are bad you'll get back "Invalid Date".

Comment: thanks. i've added some details in my question. are date1 and date 2 well formed?

Comment: What means `sum of two dates`? `today+yesterday=?` What you tried to get?

Comment: i need to add the time of date 2 to date 1...

Comment: Why not just add it? Store actual timings into your db, without unnecessary date part.

Comment: because i need to execute a query that check the rows between two times; then increment the range of time... i don't know if i explain it well, my english is bad

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You should substract zero-date from each date to manipulate with time.

```
var t0 = Date(0,0,0)).getTime();
var t1 = (new Date(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 15)).getTime() - t0; // 15000 ms
var t2 = (new Date(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 30)).getTime() - t0; // 30000 ms
var sum = t1 + t2; // 45000ms
```

---

You can use something like `moment.js` to simplify things like this:

```
var sum = moment()
  .hour('12').minute('44')
  .add(4,'hours').add(20, 'minutes')
  .format("HH:mm");
```

---

Or implement it:

```
// Convert a time in hh:mm format to minutes
function timeToMins(time) {
  var b = time.split(':');
  return b[0]*60 + +b[1];
}

// Convert minutes to a time in format hh:mm
// Returned value is in range 00  to 24 hrs
function timeFromMins(mins) {
  function z(n){return (n<10? '0':'') + n;}
  var h = (mins/60 |0) % 24;
  var m = mins % 60;
  return z(h) + ':' + z(m);
}

// Add two times in hh:mm format
function addTimes(t0, t1) {
  return timeFromMins(timeToMins(t0) + timeToMins(t1));
}

console.log(addTimes('12:13', '01:42')); // 13:55
console.log(addTimes('12:13', '13:42')); // 01:55
console.log(addTimes('02:43', '03:42')); // 06:25
```

Comment: For downvoter: it is just point to OP error, not advice to action. I see not any profit to use `Date` for this.

Comment: yes.... using date objects was not the right move... but i have two time strings in this form "hh:mm:ss". how can i sum sum those timestrings?

Answer (score 0):

summing two timesteamps could result in a value very far in the future that overflows (and from which a new Date() cannot be instanciated to a valid date if the result is a negative timestamp when internally computed with some 32 bit integers).

The "new Date(millis)" is not warrantied to cover a very wide range of dates (far in the past or in the future), but works only within a limited range of timestamps.

So the question is: what are the values of date1 and date2 ?
- If they are both absolute timestamps, their sum is a complete non-sense.
- If one is abolute and the other is a relative duration, this makes sense for a small positive durations, and the sum is an absolute timestamp.
- If both are relative, the result is also relative.
- negative relative durations may also not work with getTime(), and more generally with all cyclic calendar calculation, if they internally used some "mod" operator or some integer divisions (truncated toward zero, instead of using floor()): this could prohibit computing valid values for some fields like the year, week, month, or even just the hour (modulo 24), minute or second (modulo 60): you get get overflows/underflows, or approximations in untested/unsupported date ranges

As you've just edited it, I see that you are trying to sum two absolute dates.
When using getTime() on absolute dates, the returned values are already huge values (from an epoch far in the past), and their sum will overflow the capicity of some 32bit implementations.

So you get the negative value...

See it by yourself: log the individual values of date1.getTime() and date2.getTime()

Probably what you are trying is to compute a difference of two absolute dates, not a sum, to return a duration in milliseconds.

Comment: i create date1 and date2 from two timestamp i retrive from the db..                  like this                   var date1=new Date(1,1,1,hmin,mmin,smin,0);                 i don't know if it's the right way to sum two times

Comment: There's no overflowing happening here. `.getTime()` returns milliseconds in relation to Jan 1st, 1970. Both dates are before 1970 so they return negative values, and the sum of two negatives is negative.